# AS3 AIR for iOS get available storage space

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, flash-cs6

Am developing an iOS app with adobe air and flash Actionscript3. I need to know the available storage space in the iOS device programatically. I googled a lot, but to no help :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `File.applicationStorageDirectory.spaceAvailable` property.